# AlarmManager not calling background services

Tags: android

I am trying to set two alarms which will run two different background services. I set the alarm inside the onCreate method of my activity class. But the problem is that the service classes which are extending IntentService are not getting called, i.e. their method onHandleIntent() is not getting called. This is how I set my alarms

```
//Creating alarm for showing notifications.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //create an alarm for today if there is still time else schedule alarm for tomorrow.(Handled inside the one time alarm class).
        //FIRST ALARM..............
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActionBarTabActivity.this, ScheduleOneTimeAlarmForToday.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        //SECOND ALARM.............
        Intent i = new Intent(ActionBarTabActivity.this,RemoteNotificationService.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 111, i, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60, pi);
```

I have declared the services inside the minifest file as below

```
    <service android:name="com.nss.common.services.ScheduleOneTimeAlarmForToday" />
    <service android:name="com.nss.common.services.RemoteNotificationService" />
```

Also the alarms run properly on my old samsung phone but when I test it on my new Asus Zenfone or any other new phone, it doesn't show up.

Edit:
My logcat shows this:
`10-19 12:25:05.605      634-744/? V/AlarmManager﹕ triggered: flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.nss.zobbers/com.nss.common.services.ScheduleOneTimeAlarmForToday Pkg: com.nss.zobbers`

```
10-19 12:25:06.846      634-744/? V/AlarmManager﹕ triggered: cmp=com.nss.zobbers/com.nss.common.services.RemoteNotificationService Pkg: com.nss.zobbers
```

So I don't get it, my alarm is triggered but the service it needs to call doesn't get called? I have tried many posts but couldn't find the error. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work, but I won't accept it as my answer as maybe someone will tell the exact reason why it doesn't work. Well instead of directly calling services via alarmManager, I modified my code to call a broadcast receiver which then calls the respective service. Now it seems to work perfectly on different devices.